# Can a Norm be Induced by two Different Complex Inner Products?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.

> If $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$ and $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle'}$ for all $x\in X$ where $\langle,\rangle$ and $\langle,\rangle'$ are complex inner products, then must we have $\langle,\rangle=\langle,\rangle'$ ?

If $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, I think the answer is yes. Indeed, since
$$
\forall x\in X:\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle'}\implies\forall x\in X:\langle x,x\rangle=\langle x,x\rangle'
$$
then for $x,y\in X$ we have $\langle x+y,x+y\rangle=\langle x+y,x+y\rangle'$ and expanding we see that $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle'$.

But, in the complex case, I can only get $\Re\langle x,y\rangle=\Re\langle x,y\rangle'$ with this argument.

Comment: Have you heard of the polarisation identity?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I have. I thought that identity applies when you are given the inner-product first. Also I think that in order to prove the $[\Leftarrow]$ part of the Theorem "If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is a normed space, then $\|\cdot\|$ is induced by an inner product iff the parallelogram law holds", one uses it. But I don't know if the inner product constructed with the polarisation identity is the only one admissible. Is it?

Comment: The point @DanielFischer is making is that the polarization identity lets you reconstruct any inner product from the norm that it defines. So if two inner products define the same norm, the two inner products must be the same.

Comment: It is. You only use the fact that $\lVert x\rVert^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$ for all $x$ to obtain a representation of $\langle x,y\rangle$ using only the norm. Therefore any two inner products [well, as long as both are real or both complex] inducing the same norm are identical.