# If a norm is induced from an inner product, then that inner product is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

So a norm induced from an inner product satisfies the Parallelogram law: $\|f+g\|^2+\|f-g\|^2=2\|f\|^2+2\|g\|^2$. But why does this mean that the inner product is unique?

Comment: What do you mean "unique"? You mean "unique given the norm?" If so, look up the polarization identities.

Comment: I'm simply asked to prove that if a norm is induced from an inner product, then that inner product is unique. A side note says that, using the polarization identity, one can show a norm is induced from an inner product if and only if the norm satisfies the parallelogram law, but we aren't required to show this proof.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984977/can-a-norm-be-induced-by-two-different-complex-inner-products

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think of the law of cosines as represented in terms of the inner product.

Comment: So we have something like $h^2 = f^2+g^2-2fg\cos \theta$. How can we represent this in terms of inner products?

Comment: I said, "as represented in terms of the inner product."

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#For_vector_spaces_with_real_scalars).

(Suprisingly, it is much harder to prove that any norm satisfying the parallelogram law is already derived from an inner product: the proof for complex Hilbert spaces is [here](http://www.pcs.cnu.edu/~jgomez/files/norm.pdf). )

Answer (score 0):

What is $\|f+g\|^2-\|f-g\|^2?$